# Installing uclinux at STM32F746 board

Tags: stm32, uclinux, stm32f7

I have `STM32F746` board and I want to install uclinux at that. I've downloaded `u-boot-stm32f746-discovery.bin` and `networking.uImage` images from [emcraft site](http://www.emcraft.com/products/503#software). Now I've flashed u-boot with ST-Link utility. But I have no clue what to do with networking.uImage? Should it be flashed also at internal flash? Or at SD-card? I have no serial port but only USB and Ethernet and I use Windows 10. Any useful link or tutorial will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the networking.uImage seems to be around 1.6Mb (0x1a4d40 bytes). You will have a very hard time flashing this since the MCU you are using STM32F746NG only got **1Mb of flash**.

The load address is:

```
Load Address: c0008000
Entry Point: c0008001
```

This looks like **sdram address space** to me (FSMC peripheral). I am not sure but I would suspect that the u-boot image that you flashed will look for the image on sd-card (or ethernet ?) and copy the file **to the load address on sdram**. After this it will set the PC to start executing from from the entry point.

There might be some configuration that needs to be done in order for u-boot to understand what to do. Try and talk to the board with UART an see if you get any prompt or anything.